# Drawing a triangle using a for loop

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

Here's my problem.
Using only the characters * and +you need to form rectangular image with width m and height n (m < n) that depicts a right isosceles triangle with character + inside the rectangle made of characters * (view examples).
For each m and n read from standard input your program should output the correct image.
Attention: Do not print unnecessary empty spaces or new line characters.
Note: The correct solution of the problem is without the usage of arrays/matrices since there is no limit on m and n.
Clearance: The triangle is formed with one character + at the beginning of the first row, two at the beginning of the second row,... m characters + at the beginning of the m-th row.
Here's an example of what it should look like for the input 3 and 4 http://prntscr.com/53xv5s

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
int m, n, i, j;
scanf ("%d %d", &m, &n);
for (i=0; i<m; i++)
{
    printf ("+");
    for (j=n-1; j>0; j--)
    {
        printf ("*");            
    }
    printf ("\n");    
}    
return 0;
}
```

Any help on how to fix it? So far what I get is this
http://prntscr.com/53xvq2

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: That's an easy problem, so you can go through it step by step. Anyway, `printf("+")` prints only a single plus for every row. You need either two independent inner loops, one for `+` and one for `+`, or you need a condition to decide on `+` or `*` inside an inner loop. Obviously, both variants require you to use the current row `i` as a criterion.

Comment: Thanks for the help, and no- it's not homework, it's practice problem for an exam.

Comment: this is NOT a isosceles triangle (wherein each leg is the same length and the include angles are all 60 degrees.)

Comment: @user3629249: It's an isosceles triangle all right - it has two sides of equal length. What you mean is an equilateral triangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
int m, n, i, j;
scanf ("%d %d", &m, &n);
for (i=0; i<m; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        if(j <= i)
            printf ("+");
        else
            printf ("*");
    }
    printf ("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

This way it will always print n chars and n lines
every line will start with i +'s and end with *

Comment: @marija Funny to hear this was a practice problem for an exam as I had this exact problem on a midterm I had in first year. Good luck on the exam!

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int row, column, rowCount, columnCount;

    printf("Enter row and column length: \n>");
    scanf (" %d %d", &row, &column);

    for (rowCount = 0; rowCount < row; rowCount++) {

        for (columnCount = 0; columnCount < column; columnCount++) {

            if(columnCount <= rowCount)
                printf ("+");
            else
                printf ("*");
        }

        printf ("\n");
    }

    return 0;

}
```